# window.store is undefined using Cypress 11

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, cypress

I'm having an issue with Cypress11. When check `window.store` it returns `undefined`.
I'm looking to dispatch data allowing me to render the page in a specific configuration (which is dependent on the store data) and run some tests against it. Unfortunately I'm failing at the first hurdle. If the store is undefined then I can't dispatch to it. If someone could check my index page set up and let me know how stupid I'm being I'd really appreciate it.

Here's my set up.
index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './components/Container/App';
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { MsalProvider } from '@azure/msal-react';
import { msalConfig } from './authConfig';
import { store } from './app/store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') || new DocumentFragment());
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <App />
                </Provider>
            </MsalProvider>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>
);

type CypressWindow = Window & typeof globalThis & { Cypress: any; store: any };
const testWindow = window as CypressWindow;

if (testWindow.Cypress) {
    testWindow.store = store;
}
```

window.Cypress exists
[image: Cypress Console]

Comment: What happens if you assign it a different value, i.e. `1` or `"hello world"`?

Comment: @mstruebing it returns 'undefined' if I pass in a string instead of store